# Getting keyboard input without echo in DOS

Tags: assembly, keyboard, x86, tasm, dosbox

I am making the game "Connect Four".

The players have to enter a number between 1-4 so that the disc will drop into one of the columns. I am currently working on the first column. The problem is that you can enter any character and it will work (it only needs to work when you press '1') and I cant figure out how to fix it.

Moreover, the number appears on the left side of the screen. **How do I make it so when I enter the number it won't show on the screen?**

```
PlayerOneTurn:
    cmp [Player1Turn], 255
    je Player1Pressed1

Player1Pressed1:
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    cmp al, 31h
    je Player1Check1

Player1Check1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 0
    inc [FirstColumnArray]
    je DrawPlayer1Disc
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 0
    inc [FirstColumnArray]
    je DrawPlayer1Disc
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 0
    inc [FirstColumnArray]
    je DrawPlayer1Disc
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 0
    inc [FirstColumnArray]
    je DrawPlayer1Loop

DrawPlayer1Loop:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[Player1Draw1x]
    mov dx,[Player1Draw1y]
    mov al,[player1disccolor]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [Player1Draw1x]
    cmp cx, 38h
    jl DrawPlayer1Loop

DrawPlayer1Disc: 
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [Player1Draw1y]
    mov [Player1Draw1x], 25h
    cmp dx, 09Bh
    jl DrawPlayer1Loop
```

When run my project looks like this:

[image: A picture of the object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov ah, 1
> int 21h
> cmp ah, 31h
> ```

The DOS function that you used produces a result in the AL register!
Use `cmp al, 31h` to compare for a "1" keypress.

To **not** have the input echoed on the screen use DOS function 7 in stead of 1.

```
mov ah, 7
int 21h
cmp al, 31h
```

---

> ```
> Player1Pressed1:
>  mov ah, 1
>  int 21h
>  cmp al, 31h
>  je Player1Check1
> Player1Check1:
> ```

With this code you always execute the code at *Player1Check1*. You need to jump away from it when the input is not "1". Add a `jmp`

```
Player1Pressed1:
 mov ah, 1
 int 21h
 cmp al, 31h
 je Player1Check1
 jmp ELSEWHERE_YOU_KNOW_WHERE_THIS_IS
Player1Check1:
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I changed the code but it still doesn't work. Should I write all of my code here?

Comment: I think showing more of your code would be best. The picture you showed didn't tell us much!

Comment: I have added code. I am making the "Connect Four" game. If you don't understand my code, ask me and I will tell you what it does.

Comment: That solved one of my problems, thanks. But, It still draws a a disc when I press any key, I want it to draw the disc only if I press "1". I have changed to cmp al, 31h but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @KatomPower: `je/jmp` is the wrong way to write that.  Write `jne ELSEWHERE`, and let it fall through to `Player1Check1:` when they are equal.

Comment: @PeterCordes : That assumes of course that the branch target is within a byte displacement range.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: No it doesn't.  He's using DOSBOX, not emu8086, so 386 `jcc rel32` is available.  Maybe I shouldn't have edited out the `[dosbox]` tag :/

Comment: @PeterCordes : You did the question a disservice by doing that. Because my comment stands given the nature of the tags and question presented. I've replaced ms-dos with dosbox. Because as it was unless you review the actually image provided (as a link) then one can easily assume 8086 from info provided.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yup, agreed, my bad.  I thought other tags were more relevant, since I hadn't realized the OP's code had problems beside the subject of the question.  It's really a DOS system-call question, not specific to assembly-language at all, so I really wanted it to be tagged with `[dos`] or `[ms-dos]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : No problem. I generally don't look at the question history, so had no idea how it was originally worded/tagged. Assuming he wanted to target 32-bit instruction that would be allowed in DOSBOX he'd have to add the `.386` directive at the top of the assembler and link (using TASM with the `/3`) option