# remove last input character from console in assembly

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm try to write simple program for integer input in TASM assembly and stack with problem. I check each input character if it is digit. And if it's character i want remove last character from console input.

Something Like:

```
repeat:
        mov ah, 01h
        int 21h
        cmp al, 13                      ; if(al == enter)
        jz enterInput                   ;   enterInput
        cmp al, 30h                     ; if(al < '0')
        jl characterInput               ;   characterInput
        cmp al, 39h                     ; if(al > '9')
        jg characterInput               ;   characterInput
        loop repeat                     ; else loop
        ...
characterInput:
        ; remove last input character from console
```

Comment: You might just want to read characters without echo, so typed characters only appear on the screen in the first place if they pass your program's test and your program prints them itself.

Comment: Yes, how can i do this?

Comment: Look up the list of DOS system calls, and pick the one that doesn't echo.  Or just let me google `dos echo assembly` for you and find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630230/getting-keyboard-input-without-echo-in-dos in 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you @Peter. Sorry, i just doesn't know about echo in assembly. But if i use backspace and want to remove last character from input. What i can read about this?